# How can I display more information of my option, when I open the dropdown of my selectbox?

Tags: html

In my selectbox I want to display for the selected value only for example `Volvo`. Only if I click on the selectbox and the dropdown with the options is visible, I want to display all the information `Volvo (color: yellow, prize: 2000 Euro)`. Is this possible?

```
 <select>
  <option value="green">Volvo (color: yellow, prize: 2000 Euro)</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab (color: red, prize: 4000 Euro)</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes (color: blue, prize: 3000 Euro)</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi (color: green, prize: 5000 Euro)</option>
</select>
```

By default the selectbox should look like this:
http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/view/bildschirmfoto01wtm72krs.png

and if I click on the box it should look like this:

http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/view/bildschirmfotoeaoi6tnsy7.png

Comment: That’s not possible using HTML alone, you would need a JS solution that sets the long text when the select element has focus, and removes it again when it looses focus. A quickly hacked example using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/zn9xpuLy/ But that doesn’t work well in IE, and also has usability issues for keyboard use. Using a custom select replacement might make this easier to work with.

Comment: you try out for popover functionality for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is complete new solution. All past solutions are deleted.

There is **[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/vxjrn7fk/1/)** ...

Now, there is one `div` container. Inside container are one `div` for showing result and `select` which would be show or hide depend onclick.

`select` is hidden, and, when You click on `div` for results `select` will be showed. If You click again, `select` will hide. When You click on some value, `js` will extract only car name and show in result `div`.

Comment: no, you understood me wrong, I mean only what is written inside the selectbox.  In your example I see when I open my page a selectbox where it is written `Volvo (color: yellow, prize: 2000 Euro)`. But I need a selectbox where it is written only `Volvo`. But ONLY if I click on the selectbox, I will see the the car names PLUS the information like `Volvo (color: yellow, prize: 2000 Euro)`

Comment: Thank you, but you are writing text into the html, this is not what I need. The text should be inside the selectbox

Comment: Do You strictly need that values (color: yellow, prize: 2000 Euro) must be in `option`?

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed! Great! But why is the styling so different than a normal box?

Comment: I made that style. You can easy remove them. btw. `div` is container for selected result. There is fiddle example with removed styling for options : https://jsfiddle.net/vxjrn7fk/3/  ... Point is, I have to set `size` for `select` and by that I can manipulate with him (show/hide). That's because why look little different.